# Adjust saturation and brightness using vertical slider iOS Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, slider, brightness

I need to adjust brightness and saturation of selected image that i have using vertical slider as shown [image] ,**how can i implement this vertical slider .?** 
any help with libraries will also be great..

Comment: Use Core Image.

Comment: What is the question? Either you facing issue in adjusting saturation & brightness or in vertical slider?

Comment: check this code https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following for implementation

1) Verticle Slider :

a) Add slider to the UIView where you want at the cords normally
b) Use the method to rotate the slide using following code.

```
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
slider.transform = trans;
```

2) The brightness can be adjusted with following code.

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness: slider.value];
```

3) To change the saturation I would recommend to use a category for the UIImage to extend more functions.

```
-(UIImage*) imageDesaturated {
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *ciimage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.CGImage];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
    [filter setValue:ciimage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [filter setValue:@0.0f forKey:kCIInputSaturationKey];
    CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[result extent]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    return image;
}
```